# Update local SVN repository via command line

Tags: svn, command-line

I have a local repository for an SVN hosted online. I checked it out using Versions (Mac OSX). I'd now like to update this repository via command line, but I'm not sure how to link the svn command line to the already checked out repo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to link the command line to your working copy. Any Working Copy created by any SVN client can be operated through command line ( unless the versions are too different or something )

Just cd in to the working copy and do `svn up` to update your working copy.

Answer (score 0):

If the command is done by a "SVN User", then type `svn <action> <arguments>`.  Note that svn user commands are done in directories which are not under the svn repository (and thus may be done on any machine which has checked out the repository).

If you find that a svn command line is not available to you on some machine, you may need to install svn client software.  There are many different svn client software offerings, including command line offerings, plug-ins to windowing desktops (for menu driven command submission), and plug-ins to integrated development environments (Eclipse, NetBeans, etc.)

If the command is done by an SVN Administrator, then type the command `svnadmin <action> <arguments>`.  Note that svnadmin commands are done in directories which are under the svn repository (and thus must be done on the svn server machine).